# It is possible to create a texture that records the vertex movement of a shape key?

Tags: shaders, texture-baking, shape-keys

Good afternoon I want to know if I can create a texture that shows the vertex movements of a specific shape key in my model.
Red channel movements of vertex in X axis
Green Channel movements of vertex in Y axis
Blue channel movements of vertex in Z axis

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And how should the movement over time be recorded? In a single line of colored pixels or in a grid of pixels with specific dimensions? I'm not quite sure if I understand what you want to get as result.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I would assume from the question that it would just be the difference in vertex position with shape key at 0  and at 1.  He did not mention any animation or time period, I am thinking that must be it then.

Comment: So basically, save shape key itself to an image?..

Comment: I would interpret this as a Velocity texture

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I thought about that, too - but storing only the 0 and 1 positions would only need two pixels for a single vertex. For a large amount of vertices it would be the question how 0 and 1 state of vertex $n$ should be located on a texture.

Comment: Well, you don't need to store 0. I think shape keys only work like that as well - there is always a basis key, so only one vector should be stored the way I see it. So a Python script could save shape key as an attribute and it can be baked to a texture and that would be about it. But, OK :D  I do hesitate to look into that because it's not 100% clear if that's what is meant by the question so maybe it does need clarification after all.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Of course you are right, 0 would be the base key. Stupidly enough I was thinking about storing the end locations themselves, not just the difference between start and end, so I was missing the start to create a transition from one shape to the other... my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question fully, but if you wanted to convert a shape key to an image, you could convert it to an attribute with Python:

```
import bpy

o = bpy.context.object
shape_key = o.active_shape_key
attribute = o.data.attributes.new(shape_key.name, "FLOAT_VECTOR", "POINT")
attr_verts = attribute.data

for i,vert in enumerate(shape_key.data):
    attr_verts[i].vector =vert.co
```

And then bake it to an image in the Shader Editor:

[image]

The image may contain negative values in that case so you would have to save it as 16/32bit Float EXR, or deal with that some other way.

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you yeah this is what I wanted thank you. my last question is it won’t be better to use a gray image to be the start point and then black is -1 and white +1? Or do you think using float32 is better?

Comment: @souleater -1 and 1? In the example the blue channel is -3.63489, so it would still be "below" black. Do you want absolute or relative values? Because generally speaking X, Y and Z locations can have values far out of the -1 to 1 range, you did not specify if your vertices stay within a certain range. And relative values would not really make sense I guess... because when the shapekey is at value 0, all vertices are at 0% of their end position, at 0.5 all are at 50% and at 1 all vertices are 100% in their end position. Or I'm completely not getting what this is about. Probably that's it.

Comment: Well, even 32bit float precision in Blender sometimes reaches its limits, so encoding position data with 8 bit values as colors... I don't know... I would use 32bit Floats with EXR if that's possible. EXR is a very nice format. There would be no data loss and it's fast, compression is good and so on.  But that might be just because I like EXR format so much :D On the other hand, people do use 8 bit displacement maps, so... I think it depends on circumstances. It's hard to advise since you have not provided a lot of context - I have no idea what this is for or what's appropriate.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys sorry i will explain more What i would like is record the difference between movements of each vertex in a texture when shape key is 0 and when its 1. So i can create a shader that use that map to edit the mesh instead of a shape key. 
I noticed that even when i use the Basis shape key that dont move any vertex the code provided still apply color to it. it should be black right? because is not recording any movement. 
I was just a bit confuse since i never used EXR format so that image extension can contain numbers more than 0 to 1 but i would like .PNG to compatibility with ot

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann yeah what i was thinking is making a range where for example red goes from 0-1 and i can edit like 1 is 100m or something like this. because i want to make a shader that use this texture instead of shapekeys. but if its possible to store images with more numbers than 0-1 its better that way. with png it works? to better compatibility with other programs. but about what i want its exactly what you think. if the vertex dont move its black and if it moves by the shapekey make color.

Comment: This is starting to to sound like an XY problem. "So i can create a shader that use that map to edit the mesh instead of a shape key." - how? Why are you trying to this in the first place? Why not just use the shape kay as intended?